# Xamarin.Forms.Maps - How to draw the path bewteen two points - Polylines

Tags: maps, xamarin.forms, polyline

I'm working on a shared application projects with Xamarin. I try to make the path between two points, however, I only get a right path.. I search on the internet but without find anything interesting... In despite of this problem, only birds will be able to use this app !

I followed this tutorial for the maps : [Working with maps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/maps/)

To customise it, I followed this tutorial : [Highlight a Route on a Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/polyline/)

Thank for help !

Comment: "I only get a right path" - what does this mean?  What specifically are you having a problem with?

Comment: I'm french sorry and I don't know how to say it x) I think the correct saying is "straight line"?

Comment: the map won't plot a route for you.  You will need to use a service that does route calculations, and then plot the route yourself, like joe suggests below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to add each turn as a new route coordinate, and not just from point A to point B. To get these coordinates, you'll likely need a [3rd party service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Comment: I worked a lot since your answer. Xamarin and map are two things which doesn't works well haha, so it exists some packages to do more of things but deprecated or impossible to install... Xamarin.Forms.Map only update with MVVM pattern as well so it's a lot of problems... I think I'll try to make my own nuget package or something else, I don't where to go !

Answer (score 1):

I developed a solution 2 years ago:

https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/Map/MapPolylineProject

Enjoy !